# Flat if restriction to all curves in the base is flat

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, flatness

If $X\rightarrow S$ is a morphism of schemes, and $X\times_{S}C\rightarrow C$ is flat for all morphisms $C\rightarrow S$ from a (smooth) 1-dimensional scheme, is $X\rightarrow S$ flat?

(Is there any criterion for flatness that only involves restrictions to 1-dimensional subschemes?)

Comment: The answer is yes when $S$ is a reduced scheme over a field and $X \to S$ is locally of finite type. The only reference I can find is [these notes](http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/07-08/Spring/18.726/l_14.pdf) of Mckernan (Lemma 14.10) though there is not a proof there. This is false if $S$ is non-reduced, for example the composition $X \to S_{red} \to S$ where $X \to S_{red}$ is flat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The valuative criterion for flatness (in the reduced Noetherian context) is in EGA IV.   A statement and reference can be found on p.52 of *Neron Models* (a scan of which is available [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~cais/scans/BLR-Neron_Models/neron2.pdf)).